# Ruby on Rails - Users in Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement a Group system where a User can create a Group and other Users can join the Group.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :groups
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
    has_many :members, :class_name => "User"
end
```

When checking the owner, I can successfully use:

```
<% if current_user == @group.owner %>
```

But I'm unable to check the members of the group with:

```
<%= @group.members.count %>
```

As I run into an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.group_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."group_id" = ?
```

I think it has something to do with how my Users are setup, but can't figure it out.

Also, once I'm able to have a list containing all the Users that have 'joined' the Group, how do I add/remove Users from that?

Thanks.

Comment: `has_many :members, :class_name => "User"` will expect a `group_id` in users table, that's exactly what the error is saying.

Comment: you need to add a foreign key (`group_id`) on `users` table to get referenced by associated model `Group`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

> One User can belong to Many Groups

If one user will belong to only one group which your association says then you need to add `group_id` attribute to the `User` model or `users` table which will identify in which group the user belongs to. Currently you don't have that column that is why it is throwing an exception. Regarding the `owner` you have a `owner_id` in you `Group` table which gives you the `owner` which is an `User` object.

```
User - group_id
Group - owner_id
```

**But this way you will have only one `group` associated with the `User`, so your `has_many :groups` is of no use in `User` model. To have multiple you need another table in between:**

> One User will belong to only One Group

If one user can belong to multiple groups then you need to create one more model like `UserGroups` which will have `user_id` and `group_id`and the associations will go like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups #This can be members also using `class_name`
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: I was able to get this working with also referencing this question/answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639202/how-do-i-create-a-join-action-between-a-group-and-a-user

Answer (score 1):

A User also belongs to a group (you forgot that). 
In your group schema you need a group id so that once a group is created other users can join that specific group. Both owner and member should be of type "references" in your schema. With that you should be fine.

Comment: Could you add code to show an example? I've very new to Rails and I'm having a hard time following.